# How to retrive MQ CORREL ID and send back the same

Tags: java, messaging, ibm-mq

I am new to IBM MQ.
Can anyone post a sample java program to retrieve CORREL ID from the incoming message and set the same to the outgoing message.

I tried searching over internet. But couldnt find anything straightforward

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer 
Just retrieve the msg.correlationid and set it in a similar way